# summarizing distinct character vectors based on strings in another column

Tags: r, tidyverse

My `df` is

```
df <- data.frame(region = c(rep("fod", 5), rep("fom", 5), rep("fed", 5)),
                 genus = c('A','A','B','C','C',
                           'B','B','B','A','C',
                           "E","B","B","A","B"),
                 spp = c("A a","A a","B a","C c","C b",
                         "B","B b","B c","A c","C c",
                         "E","B a","B b","A a","B a"))
```

A fast explanation: each `genus` is a single name and each `spp` bears the `genus` name as the first word and another word (the specific name) as the second. In my case, uppercase letters are the `genus` and lowercase letters the specific names. Ok.

I'm trying to do the following: for each `region`, I'm using `n_distinct` to count the number of unique `genus` and `spp`. This can be easily performed via

```
df <- df %>% group_by(region) %>% 
      summarise(uniq_genus = n_distinct(genus),
                uniq_spp = n_distinct(spp))
```

However, I have two specific cases:

Example of case1: `region` `FOD`, line 6 of `df`, where the value of `genus` == `spp` and `B`, as a "species genus (first word of `spp`)", also occurs in line 7 and 8. In cases like this, I do not want `B` to be computed at `spp` when using `n_distinct` — the rationale is that if there are `spp` with two words already in `spp` (one of those being `B`, then `B` must be one of them, so it is not unique.

Example of case2: `region` `FED`, line 11 of `df`, where the value of `genus` == `spp` and `E`, as a "species genus" **does not occur anymore** in `FED`. In cases like this, I want `E` to be computed when using `n_distinct` — the rationale is that if there are no `spp` with two words (one of those being `E`), then `E` must be unique.

The second case, I think, can be solved simply by using `n_distinct`, however, I'm having some issues with case1, that is when the first word (in the example `B`) would be considered a unique value but it also appears in other lines as `B` + "specific name". How can I add these conditions inside a `n_distinct(spp...)`?

I'm sorry if this is too much info. I think that what I'm trying to do is much more simple than the amount of text that I wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this helps - grouped by 'region', update the `spp` to `NA` where the value of 'spp' is equal to 'genus' and the `genus` values are `duplicated` in the reverse order, then use `n_distinct` with `na.rm = TRUE`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(region) %>%
  mutate(spp = case_when(!(spp == genus & 
         duplicated(genus, fromLast = TRUE)) ~ spp)) %>%    
  summarise(uniq_genus = n_distinct(genus, na.rm = TRUE),
                uniq_spp = n_distinct(spp, na.rm = TRUE))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  region uniq_genus uniq_spp
  <chr>       <int>    <int>
1 fed             3        4
2 fod             3        4
3 fom             3        4
```

Comment: @hiperhiper noticed that the separate is not really needed.  updated

Comment: Ok, I see. Already fixed my script